# Root cannot delete folder inside freenas share?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, freenas

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and I can create directories with root but when I try to delete this old directory that Plex created it fails. Any ideas? I've tried everything what I was able to find here and online but no luck.

`root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex# df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         597M  1.6M  595M   1% /run
/dev/sda1                     590G   14G  547G   3% /
tmpfs                         3.0G   32M  2.9G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                         3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                     13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/103
/dev/loop2                    2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/199
/dev/loop3                    3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
/dev/loop1                     35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
/dev/loop6                     15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/40
/dev/loop4                     30M   30M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/26
/dev/loop5                    2.4M  2.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/180
/dev/loop8                    196M  196M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-i386/10
/dev/loop9                    3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/54
/dev/loop10                    15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/37
/dev/loop11                    87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/5145
/dev/loop12                    87M   87M     0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop13                    13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/117
/dev/loop7                    141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
192.168.1.113:/mnt/Tank/Plex  4.7T  128K  4.7T   1% /mnt/plex
tmpfs                         597M   36K  597M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                         597M     0  597M   0% /run/user/0
root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex# ls
q13
root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex# rm -rf q13
rm: cannot remove 'q13/Season 2018': Permission denied
root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex# rm -rf /mnt/plex/*
rm: cannot remove '/mnt/plex/q13/Season 2018': Permission denied
root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex# mkdir test
root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex# ls
q13  test
root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex# rm -rf test
root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex# ls
q13
root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex# rm -rf q13
rm: cannot remove 'q13/Season 2018': Permission denied
root@ubuntu-desktop:/mnt/plex#`

Answer (score 1):

The directory seems to be mounted with NFS from `192.168.1.113:/mnt/Tank/Plex` inthe output of `df`.

With NFS, by default the root user doesn't have any special privileges, you can enable them with `no_root_squash` on the server in `/etc/exports`.

You should be able to delete the file on the server, if not, there is some general problem with this directory.

Also, you should show the output of `ls -l`, not just `ls`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I was able to remove it using this while in CLI on FreeNAS `rm -R q13`

So /etc/exports does not exist on Ubuntu, do I create new file and enter just enter `no_root_squash` in it?

Comment: `ls -l` was showing that  plex user who owned q13 directory

Comment: And what are the permissions for the `q13` directory? What is the owner of the `test` directory?

Comment: Unfortunately I deleted it already so I can't tell you now. 'test' was created from Ubuntu using root account.

Comment: I turns out that I had dataset created under **Storage > Volumes** `/mnt/Tank/` and as soon as I deleted from there it was also gone from `/mnt/Tank/`.
Hope it helps someone.